# How to get the segmentation mask of an internal object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, compositing-nodes, image

I am trying to render the internal cube on top of the external cube in a segmentation mask, similar to the drawing below (please excuse my bad drawing).

[image]

I've assigned pass indexes to my materials, but I can only get the exterior cube visible in the compositor.
[image]

[image]